# AngularJS validation with custom controller method

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a form with 2 select lists. The second list is populated based on the first one. It could be that the first list contains an item with no values for the second list.

The form is valid in following situation

- Both selects have an item selected
- The first select has a selected item but no children so that can remain empty.

My list get populated correctly. When i switch selections the sub list also changes accordingly.
The validation method fires and retur the right result.

It does work in following case:

1. Select Main category with sub categories -> invalid form
2. Select Subcategory -> valid form
3. Validation succeeds

But this doesn't work and it seem to me like it should

1. Select Main category without sub categories -> valid form
2. Validation trigger and return true
3. form does not get in a valid state

This is how a added my controls:

```
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : myForm.MainCategories.$invalid && myForm.MainCategories.$dirty}">
                <label for="MainCategories" class="col-md-2 control-label">Main categories</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="MainCategories" class="form-control" ng-model="data.model.mainCategoryId" ng-options="item.id as item.Description for item in data.mainCategories" ng-required="true"></select>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.MainCategories.$error.required && myForm.MainCategories.$dirty">Required field</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-disabled="subCategoriesDisabled" ng-class="{'has-error' : myForm.SubCategories.$invalid && myForm.SubCategories.$dirty}">
                <label for="SubCategories" class="col-md-2 control-label">Sub categories</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="SubCategories" class="form-control" ng-model="data.model.subCategoryId" ng-options="item.idas item.Description for item in subCategories()" ng-required="isSubCategoryValid()"></select>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.SubCategories.$error.required && myForm.SubCategories.$dirty">Required field</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

my javascript:

```
var matrixes = [];
$scope.subCategories= function () {

    matrixes = $scope.data.CategoryMatrixes .filter(function (matrix) {
        return matrix.mainId== $scope.data.model.mainCategoryId;
    });

    var subs= $scope.data.subCategories.filter(function (cat) {
        return (matrixes.filter(function (matrix) {
            return matrix.subId== cat.Id
        }).length > 0);
    });

    $scope.subCategoriesDisabled= subs.length == 0;

    return subs;
};

$scope.isSubCategoryValid= function () {
    if ($scope.subCategoriesDisabled== true) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($scope.data.model.subCategoryId== ""){
        return false;
    }
    var isValidCat = (matrixes.filter(function (matrix) {
            return matrix.subId== $scope.data.model.subCategoryId
    }).length > 0);

    if (isValidCat == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disable second input (subcategory) and enable when main category is selected.
When main category is selected, calculate list of subcategories and:
* assign it to scope, 
* enable subcategory.

for second input I would write custom directive/validator to check:
* if subcategories.length > 0 && is selected
* if subcategories.langth === 0 => mark as valid

Search in google how to write custom valiation (`$setValidity` function is used)

ng-required should not be assigned to method (good practice), writing validation code in controller is not good ... better in directive